# Test OSX backward compatibility

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, backwards-compatibility, osx-lion

I have OSX Lion and I am building an application that should work on 10.6 and up. What are my choices to test on 10.6 since I have 10.7?

Answer (score 1):

Have a Snow Leopard test machine. Or maybe a virtualized one would be enough.

Note that virtualizing Snow Leopard Client would breach the Apple User Agreement but you can virtualize Snow Leopard Server.

Comment: Besides breaking the user agreement, can it easily be done with Parallels without any major hacks? I have a 10.6 CD handy.